# TypeError: ('Keyword argument not understood:', 'data_format')

Tags: keras, pre-trained-model

I trained and downloaded a model(a CNN) using Keras from google colaboratory when I tried to load the model on my local machine(Mac OS X El Capitan), I received the following error.

```python
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/models.py", line 243, in load_model
    model = model_from_config(model_config, custom_objects=custom_objects)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/models.py", line 317, in model_from_config
    return layer_module.deserialize(config, custom_objects=custom_objects)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/layers/__init__.py", line 55, in deserialize
    printable_module_name='layer')
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/utils/generic_utils.py", line 143, in deserialize_keras_object
    list(custom_objects.items())))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/models.py", line 1352, in from_config
    layer = layer_module.deserialize(conf, custom_objects=custom_objects)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/layers/__init__.py", line 55, in deserialize
    printable_module_name='layer')
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/utils/generic_utils.py", line 145, in deserialize_keras_object
    return cls.from_config(config['config'])
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/engine/topology.py", line 1269, in from_config
    return cls(**config)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/layers/core.py", line 483, in __init__
    super(Flatten, self).__init__(**kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/engine/topology.py", line 292, in __init__
    raise TypeError('Keyword argument not understood:', kwarg)
TypeError: ('Keyword argument not understood:', 'data_format')
```

I tried loading the model by changing the backend from Theano to TensorFlow but still got the same error.

Comment: Might be version mismatch, maybe update Keras.

Comment: Thanks a lot, @nuric I was on the version 2.1.3 and the model was trained on version 2.1.6 I updated keras on my PC and the issue was resolved.

Comment: @SiddhantBansal version 2.1.3 of what? I am having a model, but I don't know on which version it has been trained.

Comment: @mychemicalro version 2.1.3 of Keras

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You might be using a different version between platforms. Updating Keras to the same / latest should resolve the issue, with pip:

```
pip install --upgrade keras
```